# Check if at least one int of list A is less than one int of list B

Tags: python

Given a List A and B containing integers, I would like two compare both lists and return true if at least one element of List A is less than at least one element of list B, else return False.

Examples:

```
>>> A = [1,4]
>>> B = [0,2]
>>> compare_lists(A, B) # True because 1 from list A < 2 from list B

>>> A = [2,4]
>>> B = [0,2]
>>> compare_lists(A, B) # False because all elements of A are greater or equal to all B elements
```

Most straightforward implementation of this function:

```
def compare_lists(a, b):
    for i in a:
        for j in b:
            if i < j:
                return True
    return False
```

I don't think this can be enhanced performance-wise, but it there a better way using Python to achieve the same result, using a one-liner maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is enough for you to know if the minimum in `A` is less than the maximum in `B` therefore the following is enough -

```
return min(A) < max(B)
```

Comment: This is great but unfortunately less performant than then 'compare_lists' function, because you will have to iterate over all items of both lists.

Comment: That depends on the lists' structures. That is - all the elements in A beside the last one is greater than all the elements in B beside the last one. My solution will read each list once while the original solution will do N*M (N and M being the lists' lengths) comparisions.

Comment: I just realized that, came back to edit my answer but you answered before. Thanks your solution will do great then.

Answer (score 1):

Nested `for` loops might be translated into list-comprehension, `any` function allows checking for *at least one* `True`

```
A = [1,4]
B = [0,2]
print(any(i < j for i in A for j in B))  # True
A = [2,4]
B = [0,2]
print(any(i < j for i in A for j in B))  # False
```

`any` does short-circuit (i.e. end processing as soon as truthy value is encountered)

Answer (score 1):

If you combine the two other answers you get a solution that iterates over one list exactly once and over the other list at most once, but possibly does not check every element:

```
maxB = max(B)
return any(number < maxB for number in A)
```

You could also check before which of the lists is shorter and pick this one to find the maximum (if it is B) or minimum (if it is A) in the first step, then iterate lazily over the longer list.

If the lists are long and it is likely that the condition is fulfilled even when not looking at all the elements, you could optimize further by walking over both lists simultaneously and in each step update the minimum and maximum found so far. Once the minimum of A found so far is < the maximum of B found so far, you can stop and return True. The worst case is, like in the solution above, that the condition is not fulfilled, in which case both lists are walked exactly once.